# NullReferenceException throw by CompletionPortCallback

Tags: c#, .net, io, frameworks, clr4.0

```
 My applicatiion is crash twice and the stacktrace as below:

 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
 Exception Info: System.NullReferenceException
 Stack:
   at System.Net.Sockets.BaseOverlappedAsyncResult.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
```

My application use Begin/End async IO model as below:

```
 HttpRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(callback,context);
 singal.wait(3000);
 .......
 context.dispose();//the context contain buffer to be read and buffer to be sent and the networkstream.
```

Is the problem  caused by the overlapped data removed by call context.dispose method when the thread start? 
     but i must set a time to wait,otherwise the thread will be block for a long time.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing more code and knowing what `signal` is, but this doesn't look like you are using the asynchronous Begin/End methods correctly.

Comment: [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Dirk,singal is ManualResetEventSlim object, it is used to sync the asycn operation.